# How do i fix "cb is not a function" in router?

Tags: reactjs, callback, router

I am adding another parameter to my current query in my router.
But I am getting this error:

> TypeError: cb is not a function
>   at Query.client.query [as callback]

This is my code:

```
    // old code with just distance params that works
    ...
    const express = require('express');
    const pool = require('../modules/pool');
    const router = express.Router();

    router.get('/:lat/:lon', (req, res) => {
        console.log('location GET local route');

    let queryText = `SELECT *, distance($1, $2, location.latitude, location.longitude) as distance FROM location ORDER BY distance ;`
    pool.query(queryText, [req.params.lat, req.params.lon]).then((result) => {
        res.send(result.rows);
        // console.log(result.rows)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
    module.exports = router;

    // this is the current router with the error.
    const express = require('express');
    const pool = require('../modules/pool');
    const router = express.Router();

    router.get('/:lat/:lon/:type', (req, res) => {
    console.log('location GET local route');

    let queryText = `SELECT *, distance($1, $2, location.latitude, location.longitude) as distance FROM location ORDER BY distance WHERE "type" = $1;;`
    pool.query(queryText, [req.params.lat, req.params.lon], [req.params.type])// erroring here 
    .then((result) => {
        res.send(result.rows);
        // console.log(result.rows)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
pool.query(queryText, [req.params.lat, req.params.lon], [req.params.type])
```

to

```
pool.query(queryText, [req.params.lat, req.params.lon, req.params.type])
```

Comment: Thank you that is so obvious I cant believe i missed it, thank you.